# App.config values not read/detected in .Net Core 2.2 class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I am creating class library project in **.net core 2.2** which can be used in both .net core and .net framework.

Since it is class library project, I have added app.config to read configuration values. Installed ConfigurationManger from Nuget package. Below is app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="InputKey" value="12345" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And the .Net code reads value like below,

```
INPUT_KEY = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputKey"];
```

Added Nunit test project and added app.config there as well.The project builds successfully. When I debug my test case the below line always returns null.

1. Tried copy always for both app.config(class library and test project) and set Nunit test project as startup project- Not working.
2. Removed app.config[![enter image description here][1]][1] from class library project and kept only test project app.config- Not working.
3. Set Class library as startup project- Not working.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Shouldn't this be an "appsettings.json" from net standard 2+?

Comment: if i use appsettings.json can I use this class library for .Net framework projects?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22101 

<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.dll.config" />
</Target>       

I have above in .csproj of Nunit test project and it works. If some other .net framework application want to use this class library, do they need to add above code there as well?  My preference would be they have to just refer dll and use it.

Comment: @Govind all the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages are .NET Standard 2.0, so you can use them anywhere you want. You don't need to use `appsettings.json` anyway, the `Configuration` package can work with multiple providers. In fact, you should probably use the config classes *and* the Secrets feature to protect the input key during development

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have created this project as .net core 2.2. You mean to say I have to create project under .net standard instead of .net core, so that i can use it anywhere?

Comment: @Govind if you want to use your project in both runtimes without problems or warnings it has to be .NET Standard. This has nothing to do with configuration. .NET Core 2.2. has APIs that don't exist in .NET Framework. Your compiler should be complaining already when you reference the .NET Core assembly from a .NET Framework project

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah thanks. I created with .Net Standard and it works well. I have posted your suggestion as answer for this post.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild"> 
<Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.dll.config" /> 
</Target>
```

Adding above code in .csproj file resolved my issue.

Since my requirement is to use the dll in both .net framework and .net core, I have to create project using .Net Standard instead of .netcore or .netframework.

Thanks  @Panagiotis Kanavos for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can view my post [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2018/07/07/di-for-console-app-in-asp-net-core/)

> Side note: This approach for json file

First install these 2 package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

In your code

```
public static void Main()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
      var currentDir = ProjectPath.GetApplicationRoot();

     // build configuration
     varconfiguration = newConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(currentDir)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",false)
               .Build();

     serviceCollection.AddOptions();
     serviceCollection.Configure<WebJobSettings>(configuration.GetSection("WebJobSettings"));
     // add app
     serviceCollection.AddTransient<WebJob>();
}
```

Then just read like this

```
public class WebJob
{
  private readonly IOptions<WebJobSettings> _webJobSettings;
  public WebJob(
    IOptions<WebJobSettings> webJobSettings)
  {
    _webJobSettings = webJobSettings;
  } 
}
```

Comment: yes, but will the same dll work for .net framework?

Comment: this is for .net core so I dont think it will work for .net

Answer (score 0):

Keep config files out of your unit tests in the first place! Use a mock instead to deliver the config values instead. This has several advantages:

- You will be able to test different sets of config values instead of only those that are in the current config file
- You will be able to test the config values against invalid input
- You won't have to remember to always maintain another working copy of the config file
- A cleaner architecture: Unit tests in general should not get in touch with physical files but only test the behaviour of a class

The code below is a recommendation on how you can use mocking to provide the config values for your unit test:

```
// The class that is accessed in order to get some config setting
public class AppConfig
{
    // The provider reads from a physical file when your lib is shipped but in your tests it will be mocked 
    private readonly AppConfigProvider provider;

    // Constructor used by your app or library
    public AppConfig() : this(new AppConfigProvider())
    {
    }

    // Constructor that can be used by your unit testing framework to inject a mock
    internal AppConfig(AppConfigProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public string InputKey => GetConfigValueOrThrow("InputKey");

    private string GetConfigValueOrThrow(string configKey)
    {
        string value = provider.GetSetting(configKey);

        if (value == null)
            throw new Exception($"A value for key {configKey} is missing in the App.config file.");

        return value;
    }
}

// Provider implementation that actually reads from the app.config file
internal class AppConfigProvider
{
    internal virtual string GetSetting(string configKey)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey];
    }
}

// In the test class the config values will be returned by a mock instead of a physical file. This example uses Moq as mocking framework.
public class AppConfigTest
{
    private Mock<AppConfigProvider> mock;
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        mock = new Mock<AppConfigProvider>();
        appConfig = new AppConfig(mock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestInputKeyWhenValueIsValid()
    {
        mock.Setup(provider => provider.GetSetting("InputKey")).Returns("12345");

        Assert.AreEqual("12345", appConfig.InputKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: Mocking yes I can do. but my requirement is not that. I just want to replicate how other 3rd party consumers use my dll to access. because I want to use it for .net framework,.net core and other platforms it should be compatible with lower version. My question is not how to do mocking for app.config. Rather I have asked how to access app.config.